# Get url from google.maps json and save the data in a variable

Tags: json, google-maps

Good morning I need to get the data generated by google.maps distance and time from a JSON, in the documentation is this address:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=MI_API_KEY

Setting it up with my api and passing two random directions I get and show the distance and time:

```
<script>
    var respuesta = '{"destination_addresses":["Av. Sagrada Familia 627, 
Cordoba"],"origin_addresses":["9 de Julio 1800, Cordoba"],"rows":[{"elements":[{"distance":{"text":"2,2 
mi","value":3523},"duration":{"text":"9 
min","value":540},"status":"OK"}]}],"status":"OK"}'


  var distancia = JSON.parse(respuesta).rows[0].elements[0].distance.text
 var tiempo = JSON.parse(respuesta).rows[0].elements[0].duration.text

   window.onload = function what(){
    document.getElementById("span_distancia").innerHTML = distancia;
    document.getElementById("span_tiempo").innerHTML = tiempo;
  }
</script>

DISTANCE: <span id="span_distancia"></span><br>
TIME: <span id="span_tiempo"></span><br>
```

So far so good, now the start and end addresses are not static, in this example I put before are always going to be the same data, I need that data to be dynamic since to the address of google.maps step start and end as variable:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=VARIABLE_PHP_START&destinations=VARIABLE_PHP_END&key=MY_API_KEY

How can I do to read that JSON generated by Google and dynamically insert the data into the response variable so that every time I pass a start and finish I calculate the distance and time and show it to me?

Comment: I'd suggest you use the Google Maps JS API instead of their web service for this case. You can find it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix). A sample to guide you would be [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix)

Comment: I use JS but is not working, now i use web service and its working

Answer (score 0):

Finish:

```
<?php 
$start= !empty($_GET['start']) ? urlencode($_GET['start']) : null;
$end = !empty($_GET['end']) ? urlencode($_GET['end']) : null;
$urlApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=".$start."&destinations=".$end."&key=API_KEY";
$result = file_get_contents($urlApi);
$data = json_decode($result, true);
$millas =  $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
$millasKm = round(($millas * 1.60934),2);
$duration = $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
?>
Distance: <?php echo $millasKm." Km";?><br>
Duration: <?php echo $duration;?><br>
```